# When should a subclass of Control be created and when should a subclass of Panel be created?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, controls

In WPF(or silverlight)When should a subclass of Control be created and when should a subclass of Panel be created?

What are the appropriated scenarios for each of them?

Comment: Initial thought : To get a more customised panel or control.

Comment: My re to your last post explains it.

Comment: @ lukas : Thanks, I saw that. I posted this one to make the question simpler. The last one got a little too complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use custom controls when I have a rigid structure -- meaning I can lay out exactly what I want in Xaml, even if I might skin the control by having multiple Xaml definitions which look completely different.  An example would be a spreadsheet control I wrote.  One Xaml definition has a certain set of colors and layout for the menus and buttons, another is completely different.  I always know what I am laying out when I use a custom control.

I use custom panels when I have a more dynamic arrangement where I will need to override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride, and those are often virtual, meaning that I only instantiate what is visible.  An example of a custom panel is one I wrote that displays hundreds of images.  You can change the layout (e.g., a stack of pages, 2 side by side, or tiled so as many as possible will fit) and zoom level.  I only read and display the images that are visible in the custom panel, and there's a scrollbar to pan through them.

Most standard panels such as Grid, StackPanel, etc. are all custom panels Microsoft wrote.  That should give you an idea of what custom panels are used for -- to arrange an unknown number of child elements in a certain pattern.  Custom controls on the other hand are for designing a specific UI, generally one that is skinnable via Xaml styles.

Answer (score 2):

One consideration is that you will generally only create a custom control in WPF/Silverlight when you want new behavior.  If all you want to change is the appearance, this is generally possible using styles, control templates, ...